# where does nodejs event loop run?

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-loop

https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/what-you-should-know-to-really-understand-the-node-js-event-loop-and-its-metrics-c4907b19da4c

according to the above blog post,"There is only one thread that executes JavaScript code and this is the thread where the event loop is running."
but event loop is provided by libuv, and that is no javascript code.
can someone clear this above concept and also explain where does libuv run(v8 or operating system or somewhere else) and how it coordinates the tasks??

Comment: it runs on your CPU

Answer (score 0):

yes you are right (libuv (Unicorn Velociraptor Library) is a multi-platform C library that provides support for asynchronous I/O based on event loops.)  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libuv) is a link maybe this [blog](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/what-you-should-know-to-really-understand-the-node-js-event-loop-and-its-metrics-c4907b19da4c) is missing something which is not explained